# Receiving data from another app in the same device android

Tags: android

I have two applications and I want to be able to share a data such as TreeMap object between them. I have a application app1 that need a data from application app2.

How to do this in android?

note :
This two applications are developped by me and installed in the same device.

Comment: ContentProviders are the made to do this..try them

Answer (score 0):

[ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are a good approach to share data between applications.

Comment: if you have an exapmle of how to use ContentProviders, please share it with me